# What is the most elegant way to convert n-bit data stored in a matrix to integer?

Tags: r, matrix, bit, raw

I'm struggling to extract information from binary files in a fast way without making use of idiosyncratic approaches without being able to recycle code in another context at a later stage.

My actual use case encompasses binary precipitation radar data from GWS. You can pick any unpacked file from [here](https://opendata.dwd.de/weather/radar/radolan/ry/) if you like. If you acquired actual files, here is the code I used so far to get started. Basically, I was making use of `readBin() |> rawToBits() |> matrix()`:

```r
file <- "raa01-ry_10000-2207250530-dwd---bin"

con <- file(file, "rb") 

# Read ascii header
meta <- readBin(con, what = raw(), n = 141, endian = "little") |> rawToChar()

# Read 2-byte data, dim = 900*900
data <- readBin(con, what = raw(), n = 900*900 * 2, endian = "little")

close(con)

# Set dimensions
dim(data) <- c(2, 900*900)

class(data)
#> [1] "matrix" "array"
typeof(data)
#> [1] "raw"

# Create a matrix with 16 columns
bits <- rawToBits(data) |> matrix(ncol = 16, byrow = TRUE)

class(bits)
#> [1] "matrix" "array"
typeof(bits)
#> [1] "raw"
dim(bits)
#> [1] 810000     16
```

Otherwise, here is the output of `head(bits) |> dput()`:

```r
bits <- structure(as.raw(c(0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 
0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 
0x01)), dim = c(6L, 16L))
```

Data is stored only in the first 12 bits, the last 4 bits are used for flagging. But there are also 1-byte products where all bits are used for data storage. So I would need some flexibility here, I assume.

`packBits("integer")` seems to only accept 32-bit data. However, I was able to extend my 12-bit data to 32-bit using a `as.raw(0) |> rep() |> append() |> packBits()`-pipe and `apply()` this function on the matrix row-wise:

```
bits2int <- function(x) {
  
  fill <- as.raw(0) |> rep(20)
  
  append(x, fill) |> packBits("integer")
}

result <- apply(bits[, 1:12], 1, bits2int)

head(result)
#> [1] 1027 1065 1065 1065 1065 1065
```

Below the line, this approach works, but it takes approx. 12 s per file and this is way too long. Not surprising at all considering the 810,000 iterations.

Probably it would make much more sense to come up with a function which can be applied on the matrix and iterates column-wise doing some `as.numeric(x[,i])* 2^(i-1)` magic and returning the sum in the end or something the like. So this is where I am stuck at the moment.

But maybe I am just missing something evident, so I'm curious about the answers.

Thank you very much in advance!

PS: You can visualize the result via e.g. `matrix(result, ncol = 900) |> terra::rast() |> terra::plot()` if you used the actual file.

**Edit 1:**

Thought I'll mention this additional information given in the comments here also:

[`dwdradar`](https://github.com/brry/dwdradar) makes use of a Fortran routine in order to import Radolan data currently. There is an [approach using R](https://github.com/brry/dwdradar/blob/33ee711c33b77b1ef366d86be0fde69495bb0f32/R/bin2num.R#L37-L54) listed in the code for further reference, but it seems to be significantly slower. So basically, this existing code considered, I would like to know if there is a way to make the R approach a) faster and b) the `b2n(1)+b2n(2)+....` part more flexible to be applicable on n-bit data.

**Edit 2:**

Having dealt with the additional material provided in the comments, I think I'd need an equivalent for Fortran's [`IBITS()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gfortran/IBITS.html) with `position` and `length` arguments available. But this might be a more specific follow-up question, I assume. For now, I'll continue screening existing approaches.

Comment: initializing matrix and operating column-wise reduces from about 10.5 sec to 8.5 sec on my pc

Comment: Have you tried `rdwd`, `dwdradar`, or is this a different challenge? I like your workflow in their absence in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Actually, this is very much why I am asking. [`dwdradar`](https://github.com/brry/dwdradar/blob/33ee711c33b77b1ef366d86be0fde69495bb0f32/R/bin2num.R#L37-L54) makes use of a Fortran routine for importing. There is an approach using R listed but it seems to be significantly slower. So basically, this code considered, I would like to know if there is a way to make the R approach faster and the ` b2n(1)+b2n(2)+....` part more flexible to be applicable on n-bit data.

Comment: Noting that github `brry` was concerned for speed, efficiency [lists other radolan](https://github.com/brry/dwdradar/issues/4), we see [KWB-R-ver3](https://github.com/KWB-R/kwb.dwd/blob/master/R/read_binary_radolan_file_raw.R) where I'm guessing ver3 is the most improved followed by(?) [to raster ver3](https://github.com/KWB-R/kwb.dwd/blob/master/R/radolan_raw_to_raster.R), (still a little fuzzy for me), but the fortran routine or kwb approaches get you past the `packBits` padding step. As stated, the fortran is faster than R. What would the use case for n-bit flexibility be?

Comment: And since you're clearly an omnivore, let me recommend [omd](https://github.com/sangwon-hyun/omd) to your consideration,

Comment: @DonaldSeinen: `b2n` from `dwdradar` for instance takes ~110 ms on my machine and the performance would be perfectly fine from my point of view - I mean, it's several magnitudes faster than my approach taking 12 s - but somehow I'm missing this piece reducing `b2n(1)+b2n(2)+...+b2n(n)` into `b2n(bits = n)`.

Comment: @Chris: Oh, wow! I totally missed this collection. That's some content to review - will take some days, I assume. Thanks a lot again! Yeah, concerning the use case: Maybe it's simply overthinking on my side and just a matter of perception? I checked the Radolan description again and they seem to be using 12-bit and 8-bit data only. So maybe it would still be ok to end up with these 2 cases. On the other hand, I was also interested what the pros would suggest here. Maybe there is an approach being significantly faster? However, I will need to check all the functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this took some time now because I was focusing on [brry/ReadBinaryRadarFile](https://github.com/brry/ReadBinaryRadarFile) at first, realizing at some point code provided in [brry/dwdradar](https://github.com/brry/dwdradar) differs to some extent, so I had to start over again.

However, let’s have a closer look at current implementations.

**Overview:**

**1) readRadarFile calling [binary_to_num](https://github.com/brry/dwdradar/blob/master/src/binary_to_num.f90) (Fortran subroutine) @ brry/dwdradar:**

Starting with `readBin(openfile, what = "raw", n = 900*900*2, endian = "little")`, the main function seems to be a convenient wrapper for [IBITS](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gfortran/IBITS.html). It seems like `IBITS()` does exactly what is necessary here:

*IBITS(I, POS, LEN): extracts a field of length LEN from I, starting from bit position POS and extending left for LEN bits. The result is right-justified and the remaining bits are zeroed.*

This way, data from bits 1-12 can be extracted directly, as well as flags stored in individual bits 13, 14, 15, 16.

**2) readRadarFile calling bin2num calling [b2n](https://github.com/brry/dwdradar/blob/33ee711c33b77b1ef366d86be0fde69495bb0f32/R/bin2num.R#L40-L49) @ brry/dwdradar:**

Starts with `readBin(openfile, what = "raw", n = 900*900*2, endian = "little")` as well.

The R routine can be narrowed down to `rawToBits(data) |> matrix(ncol = 16, byrow = TRUE)` followed by `b2n(1)+b2n(2)+…+b2n(12)` with `b2n <- function(i) as.numeric(bits[,i])*2^(i-1)`.

Position(s) and length to be extracted have to be constructed manually without any adjustments of function arguments - not very convenient from my point of view.

**3) [read_binary_radolan_file_raw_v3](https://github.com/KWB-R/kwb.dwd/blob/c3863e2bb2342ca68fe36d1a3006e3f07d195329/R/read_binary_radolan_file_raw.R#L73-L100) @ KWB-R/kwb.dwd:**

Using `readBin()` as well, but with `"integer"` mode instead of `"raw"`:

`ints <- readBin(openfile, what = "integer", n = 900*900, size = 2, signed = FALSE, endian = "little")`

Thus, conversion to integers of two bytes each is performed internally. Since `readBin` takes 16 bits as input here, actual data and flags need to be separated retrospectively. This is done using `bitwAnd(ints, 0x0fff)` for data and `bitwAnd(ints, 0xf000)` for flags. Not sure if data is adjusted according to flagged information here before creating a raster in the end or just persisted as an attribute.

**4) [­x.radolan.parse](https://github.com/GeoinformationSystems/xtruso_R/blob/61a51e9f30902e309113277db19d38de641bdeb8/R/Radolan.R#L226-L289) @ GeoinformationSystems/xtruso_R:**

Basically, makes use of `readBin(what = “integer”)` as well, post-processing includes raster object generation and removal of flagged values based on allowed min/max values.

**5)    Referenced ressource at [moc.online.uni-marburg.de](https://moc.online.uni-marburg.de/doku.php?id=courses:bsc:project-thesis-geoei:lecture-notes:bdh:pt-ge-ln-bdh-01-9000) does not seem to be available to the public due to HTTP 403: Forbidden and cannot be evaluated at the moment.**

**6)    https://gitlab.cs.fau.de/since/radolan was not evaluated due to insufficient knowledge of Golang.**

**Benchmarking:**

Benchmarking includes the conversion from binary files as input data to raster object as output data - oh, this goes beyond "n-bit data in a matrix to integer" - whereas results are not comparable unconditionally because of variations in post-processing steps (matrix rotation, rvp6 to dbZ to rainfall intensity, definition of extent and projection of the raster object created, ...):

```r
mbm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  
  "readRadarFile_F @ brry/dwdradar" = readRadarFile_F("raa01-ry_10000-2208041200-dwd---bin")$dat |> raster::raster(),
  "readRadarFile_R @ brry/dwdradar" = readRadarFile_R("raa01-ry_10000-2208041200-dwd---bin")$dat |> raster::raster(),
  "read_binary_radolan_file @ KWB-R/kwb.dwd" = read_binary_radolan_file("raa01-ry_10000-2208041200-dwd---bin"),
  "x.radolan.parse @ GeoinformationSystems/xtruso_R" = x.radolan.parse("raa01-ry_10000-2208041200-dwd---bin"),
  
  times = 100
)

autoplot(mbm)
```

[image]

```r
mbm
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                              expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#>                   readRadarFile_F @ brry/dwdradar  27.7828  32.04745  47.73367  38.49400  41.73485 409.6813   100
#>                   readRadarFile_R @ brry/dwdradar 133.8004 144.87255 192.51376 150.62500 162.99490 566.4873   100
#>          read_binary_radolan_file @ KWB-R/kwb.dwd  41.4600  44.02860  48.17945  46.44105  50.39170  81.1589   100
#>  x.radolan.parse @ GeoinformationSystems/xtruso_R 280.3148 301.48180 357.14467 313.21170 330.93485 704.8718   100
```

Having a look at median execution times, `binary_to_num()` (Fortran) is fastest with ~38 ms, as expected. Using `IBITS()` with available parameters in mind also seems quite clean from my point of view, but compilation is required. Without raster conversion towards the end, the subroutine takes ~6 ms to finish.

Biggest surprise, at least for me, is the execution time of the KWB approach being quite close to the Fortran routine. The xtruso approach is slowest despite the same conversion used, probably due to extensive post-processing. `b2n()` was slowest before without xtruso-post-processing, and can now be regarded as mid-tier.

**Preliminary conclusions:**

- R implementation of `IBITS()` seems like a pretty clean way to solve this, but the execution time might be questionable. Also, implementation from scratch might be time-consuming, as long as there is no existing comparable approach using R.
- `readBin(what = "integer")` needs some more data cleaning retrospectively but execution time seems to be comparable to the Fortran subroutine because of `raster` overhead (which might even be decreased using `terra`).

**Final results:**

I ended up using `readBin(what = "integer")` to extract actual values from the binary files producing `SpatRaster` objects in combination with `scan(file, what = "character", n = 1, sep = "\003", quiet = TRUE)` prior to this in order to read (and subsequently parse) the ascii header, since I was not fully satisfied with any of the approaches referenced. Median execution time amounts to ~80 ms, which I'd regard as quite ok-ish in comparison to the other approaches considering I managed to eliminate several processing/attribution flaws.

Will provide a link to the function once published.